# Get Directory from User

Tags: c++, directoryservices

I'm looking for a function to get a directory path from the user; I need to solicit a place to put things.  I tried using GetOpenFileName() with .dir as a filter but no joy.  I found something called GetDirectoryViaBrowse() that sounds like it might do what I want but it's part of some wizard making package and my Visual Studio knows nothing about it.  I'd like some simple non .NET widget.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the Win32 Shell API: [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

you can use 
mkdir("your path") this function is in  library.
here is a sample code:

```
#include <direct.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
  {
    char folder[50];
    char path[]="c:/";
    cin>>folder;
    strcat(path,folder);
    mkdir(path);
    cout<<"Your folder has been created in drive C.";
    return 0;
    }
```